# Two views, same model, different collection, how to use change event on model?

Tags: backbone.js, view, model, synchronization

For my setup I have two sub-views (on the same View) that render the same type of Models, however each view uses a totally different set of Model (one displays the latest ones, the other is split in 4 subviews per category). Using filter() on a Collection doesn't work because I need 4 posts per Category and about 20 new ones.

Since they are both on the same page, when I update the model on one view, I want the same model to be updated on the second view.

I tried a couple of things:

1. Use one Collection on the mainView, fetch inside the mainView and give this common Collection to the subViews. This is working as long as both subViews are using the same set of Models, which I am not.
2. Use custom events and a Collection in each subView. When Model is updated, send a global Backbone.trigger with the modified Model, catch it on the other side and do stuff as needed. This is also working but the implementation is really not pretty or efficient. Having all the Models listen for change and only act if their id is the correct one seems counter productive.
3. Use one Collection on the mainView and one per subView, the idea being that the Collection on the mainView holds all the items and distribute them to each subView's Collection as needed. This works but fetching the data, duplicating in the main Collection and the other subView Collection is kind of a pain and requires me to hold an instance on mainView inside each subView, which I don't really want to do because each subView is a "component" and can be use in multiple places.

People online seem to do the Events way most of the time, but I wonder if someone has a better idea.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your best bet will be figuring out how to use one collection for all of your views. Sounds like the problem with filter is you end up with more than 4 and only want to show 4. When creating your sub views, can you just select the first 4 models to render, and skip the rest? http://underscorejs.org/#first is a method on controllers for that

Comment: The issue is that I need completely different sets of Models. The first subView displays 4 items per category, the second just displays the 20 last items, regardless of categories. There's no way I can ensure that in my 20 last items I will get the 4 items per category needed for the first subview, or the other way around...

Comment: Ohh ok I get you now. What I would probably do is have the model trigger the change event, bubble it up from the subView to the top level view (with the id of the model, or the model itself), and then check if that ID exists in the other collections.